# Z-Index or Layer order

Tags: css, z-index

I am working on this [This site](http://www.koodoocreative.co.uk/~lovelyla)

Most of it is in place nicely, apart from the dog. "Pet Friendly Products" As you can see he is sitting below the graphic with the fence on. So the colour overlap is going over. I ideally need the dog to sit above that layer.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following property to the dog:

```
position: relative;
```

Only positioned elements abide to z-index rules (If no z-index is defined, the layer order is defined by the actual order of the elements in the page).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.. Is the background all loading ok on your screens, just out of curiousity :)?

Comment: @StuBlackett: It does, but you might want to decrease the images sizes, my (currently slow) connection is having difficulties.

Comment: Yes, Good point the png graphics a lil on the large side. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

change your css for the class in image 
to

```
.petfriendly{
    float: right;
    left: 834px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

by positioning the image it will be positioned on top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `position` different from `static` (default value) to make the `z-index` work.

Try this:

```
.petfriendly {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: -130px;
  position: relative; // added
}
```